What is the relationship between speed and torque in a DC motor
As seen in the attached graph for the DC motor, the torque has an inverse linear relationship with the speed of the motor.
Given that torque = moment of inertia X acceleration
context: building a simulation of reaction wheels on a satellite in space in Unity. I'm a software engineer that is new to physics. I am 95% sure about my assertion in question 1 but I want to verify.
QUESTION 1
does that mean as the motor accelerates from 0 to 100, the acceleration slows down?
QUESTION 2
although, not shown in the graph. what would the relationship between speed and deceleration for braking? e.g. as the motor decelerates from 100 to 0, would the acceleration remain constant? increasing? or decreasing?
